# How Can we show jquery validation error message of one form field with another form field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator for client side as well as server side validation.

But i want to show error of one form filed with another form field.

Can anyone suggest how to acheive that?

I am using following validator class.

http://jquery-validation-php-plugin.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/trunk/Validator.class.php

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new rule in jquery validation plugin. Check this link [jquery-validate - addMethod - how to apply custom rule referencing two text boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263535/jquery-validate-addmethod-how-to-apply-custom-rule-referencing-two-text-boxe)

In this rule you can check the form field and accordingly return the value of rule.

Or otherwise you can change the rule for a field. Suppose you got a field 'firstName', so you can add your custom code like this

```
firstName:
{
   required: function(element)
   {
      // here you can add your custom code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addMethod rule for this customized validation.
For Example, if you have a form id="mainForm" with state lists in the drop down. Suppose your drop down is having id ="drpState" then, write like this

```
HTML
-------
<select>
  <option value="-1">- Select -</option>
  <option value="1">Aus</option>
  <option value="2">Mogs</option>
  <option value="3">Swut</option>
 </select>

Jquery
-------
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$.validator.addMethod("selectState", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (value.indexOf('-1'));
    }, "Please select state");

    $("#mainForm").validate({
       rules: {drpState:{selectState:true},
  });
});
```

Please refer for more : http://ssthil.blogspot.in/2012/06/jquery-validate-multiple-fields-with.html
Let me know your feedback